# Powershell array of arrays

Tags: powershell, multidimensional-array

This is building $ret into a long 1 dimensional array rather than an array of arrays. I need it to be an array that is populated with $subret objects. Thanks.

```
$ret = @()
foreach ($item in $items){
  $subret = @()
  $subRet = $item.Name , $item.Value
  $ret += $subret
}
```

Comment: I saw that one and did try using += @($subret) but still not working.

Comment: "*I saw that one and did try using += @($subret) but still not working.*" - now try using what the answer actually suggests, which is not that - the answer even explains the extra comma and why it's necessary

Comment: @ TessellatingHeckler No sarcasm or heckling required - yes had also tested with the leading comma.
@Kolob Could be. I need an array where each cell contains 2 cells(name,value). That sounds like an array of arrays to me, but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Sarcasm aside, @TessellatingHeckler is correct: `$ret += , $subret` solves the problem.

Comment: I will marks as solved by previous post. Thanks.

Comment: Note to future readers: While the linked question is indeed a duplicate, _this_ question is more focused and now also touches on arrays vs. array lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there might be other ways but arraylist normally works for me, in this case I would do:

```
$ret  = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
```

and then

```
$ret.add($subret)
```

Comment: This provided the correct results in my code. Not sure why it would not work the other way.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

It is more convoluted to create an array of tuples than fill an array with PsObjects containing `Name` `Value` as the two properties.

Select the properties you want from `$item` then add them to the array

```
$item = $item | select Name, Value
$arr = @()
$arr += $item
```

You can reference the values in this array by doing this

```
foreach($obj in $arr)
{
      $name = $obj.Name
      $value = $obj.Value
      # Do actions with the values
}
```

Comment: This returns a long 1 dimensional array of
Name
Value
Name
Value
etc

Comment: More accurately, it creates a 1-dimensional array of `[pscustomobject]` instances that each have a `.Name` and `.Value` property - which is quite different than what was asked for, which is a 1-dimensional array of nested arrays with 2 elements each, whose values are the _values_ of the input items' `.Name` and `.Value` properties.

Comment: @mklement0 Technically you can consider an object an associative array.

Comment: You probably mean _conceptually_, because _technically_ they're not the same thing in PowerShell. Also, the OP wasn't looking for an _associate_ array. Given how differently your solution works from what was asked for, I think it is a distraction - _unless_ you add a disclaimer to that effect and explain why your _different_ approach is preferable (which won't be easy to do, given that we don't know the OP's reasons for asking what they're asking for).

Comment: @mklement0 I don't understand? The OP asked for a single dimensional array with objects? Here's a quote from his question: `I need it to be an array that is populated with $subret objects`. He probably doesn't actually want a tuple for this kind of situation... it is much worse having to reference by doing `$arr[0][0]` if you want the name than doing `$arr[0].Name`. Can I get a halleluhah? It's just poor programming to do it with a tuple and makes it harder for others to understand what's going on in the code.

Comment: Ps. I'm not going to delete my question. I added an edit explaining why this is the right way. You can downvote it, but I stand by this method till the grave. This is the correct way for handling Powershell objects

Comment: @KolobCanyon: Which part of "_unless_ you add a disclaimer to that effect and explain why your _different_ approach is preferable" sounded like "delete your question" to you? _The edit is precisely what I suggested you do_. Whether it is what the _OP_ actually wanted is unknown at this point (in the absence of further information, it is futile to speculate about what the OP "probably doesn't actually want"), but with the edit at least _future readers_ can decide what's right for them, without getting confused as to why you're solving a _different_ problem.

Answer (score 1):

The suspected preexisting duplicate question is indeed a duplicate:

**Given that `+` with an *array* as the LHS *concatenates* arrays, you must *nest* the RHS with the unary form of `,` (the array-construction operator) if it is an array that should be added *as a single element*:**

```
# Sample input
$items = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = 'n1'; Value = 'v1'}, 
         [pscustomobject] @{ Name = 'n2'; Value = 'v2'}

$ret = @()  # create an empty *array*
foreach ($item in $items) {
  $subret = $item.Name, $item.Value  # use of "," implicitly creates an array
  $ret += , $subret # unary "," creates a 1-item array
}

# Show result
$ret.Count; '---'; $ret[0]; '---'; $ret[1]
```

This yields:

```
2
---
n1
v1
---
n2
v2
```

The reason the use of **`[System.Collections.ArrayList]` with its `.Add()` method** worked too - a method that is generally **preferable when building *large* arrays** - is that **`.Add()` only accepts a *single object* as the item to add, irrespective of whether that object is a scalar or an array**:

```
# Sample input
$items = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = 'n1'; Value = 'v1'}, 
         [pscustomobject] @{ Name = 'n2'; Value = 'v2'}

$ret = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList # create an *array list*
foreach ($item in $items) {
  $subret = $item.Name, $item.Value
  # .Add() appends whatever object you pass it - even an array - as a *single* element.
  # Note the need for $null = to suppress output of .Add()'s return value.
  $null = $ret.Add($subret)
}

# Produce sample output
$ret.Count; '---'; $ret[0]; '---'; $ret[1]
```

The  output is the same as above.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive discussion and apologies to all for any confusion the wording of my question may have induced. I really appreciate you all shedding some light on this.